# Открыть БД для чтения и записи

Tags: android

Метод getReadableDatabase() - открывает БД для чтения.
getWritableDatabase() - для записи. 
А есть ли метод, который открывает БД для чтения и записи одновременно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они оба открывают (и создают, если база отсутствует) базу и на чтение и на запись.

Разница в деталях:
 `getReadableDatabase()`  не бросит исключение, если доступно хотя бы чтение (например из-за недостатка места на диске он вернет БД с доступом только на чтение, а не выдаст исключение о не полученом доступе)

`getWritableDatabase()`  бросит исключение в любом случае отказа в доступе (хоть на чтение, хоть на запись).

Comment: т.е. я могу для БД вызвать метод getReadableDatabase() и сделать update?

Comment: @Сергей да, можете вызвать

Comment: спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

В оф доках так:

```
getWritableDatabase()
```

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
>   writing.

Создает или открывает базу, которая будет использоваться для чтения и записи.

Ссылка [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()):