# Android&SQLite: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException при получении одной записи по ID

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Написал метод для получения записи по указанному id:

```
public NotesData getInboxItemByID(String id){
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    cursor = db.query(DataBaseContract.NotesData.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DataBaseContract.NotesData._ID},
            DataBaseContract.NotesData._ID + "=?", new String[] {id}, null, null, null);

    int idColInd = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseContract.NotesData._ID);
    int dateAndTimeColInd = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseContract.NotesData.COLUMN_DATETIME);
    int titleColInd = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseContract.NotesData.COLUMN_TITLE);
    int noteTextColInd = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseContract.NotesData.COLUMN_NOTE);

    NotesData notesData = new NotesData(cursor.getString(idColInd),
            cursor.getLong(dateAndTimeColInd), cursor.getString(titleColInd), cursor.getString(noteTextColInd));

    dbHelper.close();
    db.close();

    return notesData;
}
```

Приложение падает с такой ошибкой:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Во-первых, мне не понятно, как такая ошибка возникла: ведь напрямую `-1` я не запрашивал. Вероятно, следовало поместить курсор в начало перед выполнением запроса, но он не инициализирован перед запросом.

Comment: В связи с вашей правкой - разница в методах [минимальна](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598733/177345).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ и комментарий. У меня возникла другая ошибка - `Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.`, при этом метод для получения всех записей работает корректно, т. е. таблица заполнена. Пока думаю над формулировкой нового вопроса.

Comment: Какой то из методов `getColumIndex()` возвращает -1, это значит, что колонки с таким именем нет в БД или она не включена в выборку из БД (получены не все колонки). отосительно вашего запроса - вы запрашиваете только колонку ID , без колонок содержащих данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При получении выборки курсор не спозиционирован ни на какую запись в этой выборке и указатель курсора находится **перед** первой позицией, поэтому возвращает текущий индекс (позицию указателя в курсоре) = -1. Перед получением данных из курсора нужно установить позицию из которой брать данные (определенная запись) - `moveToPosition()` или на начало - `moveToFirst()`. Для итерации по курсору с несколькими записями использовать метод `moveToNext()` - каждый новый вызов метода перемесит указатель курсора на  следующюю запись в выборке

```
cursor = db.query(DataBaseContract.NotesData.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DataBaseContract.NotesData._ID},
            DataBaseContract.NotesData._ID + "=?", new String[] {id}, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();

int idColInd = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseContract.NotesData._ID);
...
```

перемещать указатель нужно после выполнения запроса, перед запросом курсор не содержит данных и перемещать в нем указатель некуда в принципе.