# как сделать синхронизацию с ListView из диалогового окна?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Метод **notifyDataSetChanged()** не изменяет **сразу** список, после удаления строки в базе данных. Подскажите, что нужно сделать? Спасибо. Это уже **исправленный** правильный код.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {

    //---alert_one
    builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert1 = builder1.create();
    layoutInflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    layout1 = layoutInflater1.inflate(R.layout.alert_one, null);
    alert1.setView(layout1);

    buttonAlert_oneDelete = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert_oneDelete);
    buttonAlert_oneUpdate = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert_oneUpdate);
    buttonAlert_oneCancel = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert_oneCancel);

    buttonAlert_oneDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      //удаление данных
      funDelete(id);

      //синхронизация с ListView НЕ ПОНАДОБИЛАСЬ
      //simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      alert1.cancel();
     }
    });

    alert1.show();
   }
  });
```

метод удаления

```
//метод : удаление данных
 private void funDelete(long id) {
  //***УДАЛЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ***

  //запись в БД
  db = abcDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

  //удаление данных
  db.delete(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id), null);

  //получаем новый курсор с данными
  getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();

  //***ПРЕЗАПИСЬ ДАННЫХ***

  //список столбцов из таблицы БД, которыми будет заполнен курсор
  String[] columns = {AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_EN, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_RU};
  //источник данных - курсор
  cursor = db.query(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

  //список столбцов из таблицы БД
  String[] from = {AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_EN, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_RU};
  //список элементов из файла разметки списка
  int[] to = {R.id.textViewItem1, R.id.textViewItem2, R.id.textViewItem3};

  //адаптер
  //контекст, файл разметки списка, курсор, список столбцов, список элементов, флаг
  simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, 0);

  //НОВАЯ устанавка адаптера для списка
  listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
 }
```

Comment: а где код funDelete(long id)? Если ваши данные хранятся в Cursor, то только передавать новый Cursor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026719/how-to-update-listview-in-case-of-cursoradapter-usage]

Comment: `private void funDelete(long id) {
  db = abcDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  db.delete(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id), null);
 }` Уважаемый  Andrey Mihalev, вот код метода.

Comment: а он вообще удаляется? Почему используется getReadableDatabase? Да и в любом случае changeCursor для адаптера делать придется. Либо писать свой адаптер.

Comment: Да, удаляется, если закрыть приложение, а потом открыть заново.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev между `getReadableDatabase` и `getWritadableDatabase` [разница минимальная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598733/177345) и в данном случае ни на что не влияет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не учли, что удалив что-то из БД вы не получите автоматического обновления списка данных для отображаемого списка. Т.е. вам надо вручную обновить список данных, которые у вас отображаются. Либо вручную удалив удалённый из БД элемент или зановов сделав выборку из БД. Только после изменения списка данных, коий отображается на экране нужно вызывать `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: Уважаемый ЮрийСПб! Вы совершенно правы! Спасибо Вам большое! Перезапишу код с правильным ответом. В моем случае, синхронизация не понадобилась.